# Why printf("\101\102\103\104\105\12"); print ABCDE

Tags: c, printf

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("\101\102\103\104\105\12");
    return 0;
}
```

In gcc compiler when I execute this code it prints `ABCDE`. If I call `printf` with a string like `printf("\1011\102\103\104\105\12")`
it prints `A1BCDE`. Why does it behave like this?

Comment: Because `'A'` == 65 (base 10) == 41 (base 16) == 101 (base 8).  Similarly for `'B'`, `'C'`, etc.  In short `\101` is interpreted as an octal number, so the byte '0x41' is added to the stream.  `\1011` is just that value followed by the value for `1` in the character set. (Most likely 49 (base 10))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Certain characters can be represented in character and string constants by escape sequences like \n (newline); these sequences look like two characters, but represent only one. In addition, **an arbitrary byte-sized bit pattern can be specified by '\ooo' where ooo is one to three octal digits (0...7)** or by
> '\xhh' where hh is one or more hexadecimal digits (0...9, a...f, A...F).

-- K&R "The C Programming Language" Chapter 2.3

Pay particular attention to the phrase "*one to three octal digits*"

Answer (score 3):

`\101` produces byte 101 octal = 41 hex = 65 decimal. Your terminal displays that byte as `A` since it expects UTF-8 or some other ASCII-derived encoding, and that byte maps to `A` in those encodings.

Octal escape sequences can be up to three digits long, so the extra `1` is just a `1`.

Answer (score 2):

From my studies, I found out that they're called octal escape sequences, where each 3 digits after the `\` are considered a octal number. In your case:

`\101` in octal is equal to 65 in decimal , which in ASCII code is 'A' .

Similarly,
`\102` represents 66 in decimal, which in ASCII is 'B'

`\103` represents 67 in decimal, which in ASCII is 'C'
and so on...

But in the case of `\1011`, it printed `A1` because only the first 3 digits were converted to decimal .i.e. `\101` was valid but not the `1` after it. So `\101` is A, and 1 is simply 1.

Hope that helped you. Dunno why'd you use these anyways

Comment: "_Dunno why'd you use these anyways_" Not `'A'-'E'`, but it is useful, on occasion, to know that `"ABC\0DEF"` can be used to put, for instance, two (or more) C strings in one package. One shouldn't scoff at a beginner who's merely gathering esoteric knowledge.

Comment: Again, not `'A'-'E'`, but... Not all compilers interpret `\e` as `ESC` (particularly older compilers.) It's useful to know `\033` will ALWAYS work as intended. It's also useful to know the 3 digit version `\033` is _safe_ to prepend to another digit that may be in the range `'0'-'7'`... As the OP experienced, the (apparent) 4th digit is NOT part of the 3 digit escape sequence.